# Trying to call a VBA object with a numeric name

Tags: vba, object

I have a VBA object and I'm trying to call a property of a child object

```
Object.key1.1.property
```

I'm getting an error because the name of a nested object is a number

if I use

```
Object.key1.[1].property
```

I get a runtime error 438.

Does anyone know how I can call this property?

Update: A bit of background info. The object (collection rather) is created out of a JSon string via a Json parsing macro. [See snip of the locals window to understand how the collection is organised.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrVW2.jpg)

Based on the picture of the locals window, I've tried using:

```
JsonObject.data0.item(1).AccountTypeID
```

to get a value, but the item method doesn't work.

Comment: What sort of VBA object has a numeric name?  Are you sure it isn't an index?  (e.g. `key1` might return a collection or array, which you could index as `Object.key1(1)` and obtain the `property` property of that position of the collection/array using `Object.key1(1).property`)

Answer (score 0):

I have to say I can't even envisage a way to create a property in VBA whose name is a number. I don't believe you can do it within VBA and I wasn't aware it could be done even if you created your own library. So the most obvious question is are you sure you've got that property reference correct?

Assuming there's a theoretical possibility of such a property existing, then it might be possible to call it within VBA via the `CallByName()` function, which can retrieve a property by its name, passed as a string.

Let's say you wanted to access the `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` property - ie, in your terminology, the desired child object were `Rows` and its desired property `Count` - then you could actually do so using the following syntax:

```
Dim childObj As Range

Set childObj = CallByName(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet, "Rows", VbGet)
Debug.Print childObj.Count
```

The problem you've posted is so far-fetched that I can't even create a test object with a property called `1`, so I'm unable to verify this for your specific example, but maybe, JUST MAYBE, the function could work for you:

```
Set childObj = CallByName(Object.Key1, "1", VbGet)
Debug.Print childObj.Property
```